# Read all the data from one row of matrix

Tags: python

I am reading a .mat file using python

```
mat= sio.loadmat('C:/Users/machine-learning-ex3/ex3/ex3data1')
print(mat['X'])
print(mat['X'].shape)
```

The out put looks like

```
[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]
(5000, 400)
```

How can I check only all the data of one row.
While trying it gives error like:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html), loadmat returns dictionary with key as variable name and value as the loaded matrix. From your print statements,
mat['X'] is a 2-d array.

For showing ith row, simply write

```
mat['X'][i]
```

Where i is the index of the row.

PS: you didn't mention what did you try to get that error. If you still have problems, mention that too.